# Reference a Thread Group which has a set of samplers in Jmeter in an another test plan?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to reference a thread group (which has samplers in it) in an another test plan. Can I do this in jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a [Thread Group](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/guide-jmeter-thread-groups/) can be added in the another test plan. With the help of [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller)

1. Create a Test Fragment underneath the Test Plan
2. Add any desired samplers, controllers etc. below it.
3. Then save the Test Plan - this file is now ready to be included as part of other Test Plans.

Please note:

> If the test uses a Cookie Manager or User Defined Variables, these should be placed in the top-level test plan, not the included file, otherwise they are not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thank you buddy. :)